# Error publishing webforms project

Tags: c#, webforms, web-optimization

I have a C# webforms project running in .net 4.6. When I try and publish in debug  I get the following error :-

> Unknown server tag 'webopt:bundlereference'.

This tag appears in my master page as the following: -

```
<webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Styles/css" />
```

It seems to compile okay, the error only appears when I try to publish

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it, I just added this reference at the top of the page:-

```
<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" %>
```